# Probability and random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, can I assume that it is induced by a random variable $X$ ?

A real random variable $X$ is a measurable function from a measure space $(\Omega , F)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, B)$  where $F$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ and B is the borel sigma algebra.

The probability measure $P:F\rightarrow[0,1]$ with the proprieties that $P(\emptyset)= 0$ and is $\sigma$-additive.
The probability induced on $(\mathbb{R}, B)$ is the function $P_X$ defined by $P_X(A)= P(X^{-1}(A))$, $A$ Borel set.

Comment: ok and moreover, if I have two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$, can i assume that they are induced by two random variables $X$, $Y$ respectively and and that these two random variables are indipendent?

Comment: ok thanks. And would you be able to explain me briefly why? Thank you :)

Comment: Yeeeeesssss. DO IIITTTT @AlexFrancisco :) :)

Comment: ahahah ok:) have a nice day!

Comment: Why two close votes? I think it's an interesting question. I learned something from drhab's answer.

Comment: Please add to the question the definition of "a measure induced by a random variable". In fact, it might be also useful that you add the definition of a random variable (Unless you feel like you completely understand the notion). It looks (to me) that you misunderstand one of these definitions so I think it'll help us to help you.

Comment: @Yanko done it:)

Comment: @Yanko by the way i understood the problem, it suffices to take X = Id from R to R

Comment: @tommycautero Oh that's a tricky question. In principle you are right buy just to make sure you should notice that $X$ is not just a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the domain of $X$ is a measure space **with a probablity measure**. Indeed if $\mathbb{R}$ is a equipped with a probability measure $P$ and you take $X:(\mathbb{R},P)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the identity map then, indeed the induced probability is $P$.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf P)$ a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a function that satisfies $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A$ for every Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$.

It induces probability measure $\mathsf P_X$ on measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ where $\mathcal B$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ and is prescribed by $B\mapsto\mathsf P(X\in B)$. Where $\mathsf P(X\in B)$ is an abbreviation of $\mathsf P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\})$

Now if $Q$ is some probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ then we can apply the following trick to make it a probability measure induced by a random variable.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf P):=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B,Q)$ and prescribe $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by $\omega\mapsto\omega$.

Then $X$ is evidently a random variable and this with: $$\mathsf P_X(B)=\mathsf P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\})=Q(B)$$Or shortly:$$Q=\mathsf P_X$$